# Mysql: how to join 2 columns from same table and use another table for reference

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables both columns in table A use table B as a reference.  I tried to use a inner join but I get only one column result. 
For example.

```
Table A
Reciever | Sender 
       1 | 2
       1 | 3

Table B
id | Name | Lastname
1  | James | Todd
2  | Jimmy | Jones
3  | Tom   | Brown

Desired result from joining the tables would be

Table A
Reciever | Sender
James Todd | Jimmy Jones
James Todd | Tom Brown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(t1.Name, ' ', t1.Lastname) As Reciever,
  CONCAT(t2.Name, ' ', t2.Lastname) As Sender
FROM
  TableA INNER JOIN TableB t1 ON TableA.Reciever=t1.id
  INNER JOIN TableB t2 ON TableA.Sender=t2.id
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/023c6c/1).